# ESP32 - esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup() and interrupt on the same GPIO

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm using `esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(GPIO32, 0)` to wakeup the ESP32. I also have attached an interrupt to GPIO32, with an ISR that simply implements a counter: `void IRAM_ATTR its_raining_isr() { rain_counter++; }`.

My question isn't about the code, but rather about the behavior of the ESP32 in this situation: when in deep sleep and GPIO32 goes LOW, it will wakeup the ESP32, but will it also fire the ISR that I have attached to GPIO32? Thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning of “I have attached to GPIO32”?

Comment: I have attached an interrupt to GPIO32, and the question is whether the Interrupt Service Routine that's attached to that interrupt / GPIO will be called when the ESP32 wakes up because of activity on that GPIO.

Comment: You can test that by turning on an LED inside the ISR to see if it gets triggered, so that it helps to answer the question yourself. Or alternatively, provide your code or elaborate your usage case and the problem you are facing.

Comment: I know I can test it, and I will as soon as my PCB's arrive. I asked here only to see if someone might know the answer off the top of their head. I'll close this.

Comment: The answer is "its depend on your use case". But we don't know your intension and we don't know how you setup `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(whichPin), its-raining_ISR, mode)`, so we can't really answer it. If you want esp32 be able to wake up when it is raining, you may wan to take a look at [ULP Coprocessor Wakeup](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html#ulp-coprocessor-wakeup), I can only guess what you want.